# Can any integer $c$ exist that satisfies this Logarithmic Equation?

Tags: number-theory

Suppose that $m$ and $n$ are integers $> 1,$ and that $(\log m)/(\log n)$ is rational, say equal to $a/b$ with $(a, b) = 1.$ Show that there must be an integer $c$ such that $m = c^a,n = c^b.$

This was a question from the book, "An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers " by Niven, Zuckerman, Montgomery.

My (possible) solution is :

We write, $\log m/\log n$ as $\log_{n}m.$ But then, $\log _n m=a/b$ so, $\log_nm^b=a\implies m^b=n^a.$ We observe that if, $x\in\Bbb Z$ then, we note that, $m=x^a$ and $n=x^b$ satisfies $m^b=n^a.$ Thus, $c=x.$

---

Precisely, any integer, $x$ works! This looked a bit too trivial and immediate. Have I missed something?

I want to know whether they intended a solution like above or not ?

Comment: $m$ and $n$ are given to you and you have to find $c$ in terms of these numbers.

Comment: The last step is too glib.  There are many solutions to $X^b=Y^a$, as you have noticed.  That doesn't mean that any two solutions must coincide.

Comment: To stress, the conclusion you reach is clearly too strong.  Consider $\frac {\log 2}{\log 2^2}=\frac 12$.  For the original claim, we immediately see that $c=2$ works.  But you claim that $x=5$ would also work...yet $2\neq 5^a$ for any integer $a$.

Comment: I don't understand.  Given $m=2$, $n=2^2$ your job is to find an integer $c$ such that $2=c^a$ and $2^2=c^b$ for appropriate integers $a,b$.  Of course, $c=2$ works, $c=5$ fails, though you claim it ought to work.

Comment: Well, the example I gave suggests that you should look at the prime factorizations.  I suggest starting by showing that $m,n$ must be divisible by the same set of primes, $\{p_i\}$.  Then look, say, at the case of two prime factors (the case of one prime factor is trivial...why?)

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to chat about it.  Now that you see where the difficulty in the problem lies, try it yourself for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have, $\frac{\log m}{\log n}=\frac{a}{b}$ with $(a,b)=1.$
This can be simplified to $b\log m=a\log n\implies m^b=n^a.$

The question basically asks to find an integer $c$ for every $m,n$ satisfying $m^b=n^a$ such that $c^a=m,c^b=n.$

Using the observation, that if, $p|m$ then it means, that $p|n,$ let the canonical prime factorisations of $m=p_1^{a_1}...p_r^{a_r}$ and $n=p_1^{b_1}...p_r^{b_r},$ where, $a_i,b_i\gt 0.$

Now, $m^b=n^a\implies a_ib=ab_i.$

We note that, $a_i/a=b_i/b\implies \prod p_i^{a_i/a}=\prod p_i^{b_i/b}\implies m^{1/a}=n^{1/b}=c\text{ ( say )}.$

Hence, the required $c$ is $c=\prod p_i^{a_i/a}.$

Answer (score 0):

From $m,n>1$ we can deduce $a,b\ge 1$ as well (positivity of $a$ will be used later).

$\dfrac{\ln m}{\ln n}=\dfrac ab\iff \dfrac{\ln m}{a}=\dfrac{\ln n}{b}=k\in\mathbb R\quad$ so let's call $c=e^k$

*Note: we don't know yet if $c$ integer, we just exhibited a real $c$ for which $m=c^a,n=c^b$ is satisfied.*

By Bezout since $\ \gcd(a,b)=1\ ,\exists u,v\text{ integers }\mid au+bv=1$

In particular $\ m^un^v=c^{\,au}c^{\,bv}=c^{au+bv}=c^1=c$

Since $m^un^v$ is rational ($u,v$ can be negative) so is $c$

But if $c=\frac pq$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$ then $m=c^a=\dfrac{p^a}{q^a}$ which is only possible for $q=1$

(i.e. since $a\ge 1$ then $q\mid mq^a\implies q\mid p^a\implies q=1$)

And therefore $c$ is an integer.